# Website solution, involving text fields and drop down menus combined with user input to produce Latex code?

Tags: templates, forms, javascript

I'm trying to think about this:
I would like to create a website to automate the generation of a pdf document. Originally this pdf document is generated by latex, but people are not so good with latex, so it causes a lot of trouble and time loss to keep generating that pdf document that way. So the idea was to create a website and integrate javascript and latex commands. Create the needed fields for the users to fill and generate a pdf. Now we have a latex template for that pdf, organized and divided in multiple .tex files and i would intend to use that template, but in a more userfriendly way by creating a website which automatically fills that template without the final users having the need to touch the .tex documents at all. Do you guys have any idea or can point me out to getting started on how I could achieve this. If it's not clear, i apologize, but english isn't my main language. I hope it is clear enough to be understood.

Comment: A good starting point is to enter ctan and other search terms into google: it will direct you towards resources on ctan.org, if any.

Comment: What do you want the interface to be like? You could, e.g., embed a markdown or richtext editor into the page, and then use something like pandoc on the backend to convert the markdown or html to latex. (Maybe use mathjax or katex if you need to support complex math.) It's not really clear which part of the process you need help with.

Comment: Well, I'm more of a cybersecurity guy, so I'm not really into web development actually. This would be my first time developing a website. 
The look of it, as of right now, is nothing to be worried about. The functionality though, that's something that worries me. :)

I'm going to search about ctan.